# Is there a method for adding one NSString for NSData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on writing to a file one user input on a textField.
So far I have one NSFileManager which writes data to a file. Still, I have no way of putting the textField input inside a file.

Is there a way do add a string value to NSData so I can write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get NSData from NSString,

```
NSData *newData = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

use encoding that fits your case.
append the obtained data to existing NSData,

```
[existingData appendData:newData]
```

Note: "existingData" should be an instance of NSMutableData.

Comment: Note that you'll need to use the same encoding as the original data. It might be worth going the other way—decoding the original data back to a string, appending the new string to that, and re-encoding—to ensure that consistency.

Comment: @Peter Hosey agreed, but this looks direct approach for the problem in hand (atleast for the question) as user has idea on encoding he will be using.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: It depends on whether or not you can safely assume the data is in a specific encoding. If you can, then @Tatvamasi's answer will work as written. If not, the only safe way is to decode, using the method that guesses the encoding, then re-encode afterward using the same encoding.

Comment: @Pete: It seems to me like catching encoding errors in the binary blob is beyond the scope of the function, and adding such a feature would make the function unusable if you wanted to e.g. append a string to a binary file.  So the `NSData` might *not* contain character data to begin with.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: I'm not talking about encoding errors in the original data; I'm talking about keeping the encoding of the new data consistent with the encoding of the original data. If the original data is non-textual, appending textual data to the end of it probably doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: we need to know the encoding of original data in any case,@Peter Hosey's approach  simplifies the interface : `-(NSString) DoWhatever:(NSString*) exstingDataInString` - in this method user can work with NSString's not worrying about encodings. let the caller of this method do the encoding/decoding stuff. This makes life simpler for `DoWhatever:` method(s). I believe it is up to @Matoe to pick which approach works for him the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code as your reference.

```
NSString* myString   = @"Is there a method for adding one NSString for NSData";
NSData* myData=   [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Actually I was referring to NSData not NSDate :)